# how to create xml file in objective c cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata, nsxmldocument

I m new to xcode and objective c cocoa framework and i want to write xml data to xml file placed in my cocoa project's resources folder but i cant write data to file. Anybody help please.

```
NSXMLElement *root = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"Request"];
[root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute1" stringValue:@"Value1"]];
[root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute2" stringValue:@"Value2"]];
[root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute3" stringValue:@"Value3"]];

NSXMLElement *childElement1 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"ChildElement1"];
[root addChild:childElement1];
[childElement1 release];

NSXMLElement *childElement2 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"ChildElement2"];
[childElement2 addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"ChildAttribute2.1" stringValue:@"Value2.1"]];
[childElement2 setStringValue:@"ChildValue2.1"];
[root addChild:childElement2];
[childElement2 release];

NSXMLDocument *xmlRequest = [NSXMLDocument documentWithRootElement:root];
[root release];
NSLog(@"XML Document\n%@", xmlRequest);//till this art code runs fine.
but when next part starts i got bad exception and code stops.
NSData *xmlData = [xmlRequest XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
[xmlData writeToFile:@"/Users/halen/Documents/project3/xmlsample.xml" atomically:YES];
[xmlRequest release];
```

I dont know whats the problem is there is any problem with the xml file placement. where to place xml file?? And what is right way to write xml data to .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

writeToFile: expects a path. 
You haven't supplied a valid path.

Comment: I have also given complete path (see updated code in my question) but error is same:(

Comment: Try one of the writeToURL methods. Create a file URL from the path string. Supply an NSError and check the error if the method returns a BOOL value of NO

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"/Some/Path/foo.xml"
                            contents:xmlData
                            attributes:nil];
```

Comment: it is placed in my project's resources folder/ in other word in my project then what path should i give to it??

Comment: and please can you explain how to use the method you mentioned?

Comment: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files - enjoy

Comment: I have also given complete path see updated code in my question but its still giving error .. :(

Comment: Hmmm... Why do You need write to recourse folder? If this is iPhone app - write to documents folder.